# Canvas drawing images

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm having a problem with drawing images. Everything works fine when I use `c.fillRect()` but the `drawImage()` isn't working for some reason.The image is in the same directory as the file and the variable box is defined outside of the function.

```
        window.onload = function () {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("map");
            var c = canvas.getContext("2d");

            var s = {
                rows: 10,
                cols: 10,
                width: 60.2,
                height: 60.2
            };


            var box;

            init();

            function init() {
                box = new Image();
//here
                box.src = "box.png";

                drawCanvas();
            }

            function drawCanvas() {
                c.clearRect(0,0,700,700);

                for (var i=0; i<s.rows; i++) {
                    for (var n=0; n<s.cols; n++) {
                        var x = n*s.width;
                        var y = i*s.height;
//here
                        c.drawImage(box,x,y);
                        //c.fillRect(x,y,60,60);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Anything in the dev console log?

Comment: nothing there which involves the functionality of the script.